# Finding any rows where the latest event time is over a specified period

Tags: sql, postgresql, opennms

The relates to OpenNMS where I'm trying to write an automation in SQL. I have a system which sends events to a table every time the backup succeeds. I want to detect if the backup is overdue for any given node. So for example the (simplified) table looks like:

```
nodeid, eventid, eventuei, eventtime
  1   ,  1     , backupOk, 09:20 15/12/09
  2   ,  2     , backupOk, 09:25 15/12/09
  3   ,  3     , backupOk, 09:30 15/12/09
  1   ,  4     , backupOk, 09:20 16/12/09
  2   ,  5     , backupOk, 09:25 16/12/09
  2   ,  6     , backupOk, 09:25 17/12/09
  3   ,  7     , backupOk, 09:30 17/12/09
```

So what I need is a list of nodeid's where the backup is overdue by 24 hours (and I guess where no backup has occurred at all, although there are nodes in this database that don't get backed up (as they are different types of node)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting list of nodes that were not backed up - from your schema  that you showed us - is not possible.

Getting list of nodes that are 24 hours overdue is trivial:

```
select nodeid, max(eventtime)
from your_table
group by nodeid
having max(eventtime) < now() - '24 hours'::interval
```

Comment: What additional information is needed? I can for example do another query that will list all nodeid's that should have backups running on them.

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL is for Oracle but I'll assume there are similar time-handling facilities in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT E.NODEID, E.LAST_BACKUP_TIME
  FROM (SELECT NODEID, MAX(EVENTTIME) AS LAST_BACKUP_TIME
          FROM BACKUP_EVENTS
          WHERE EVENTUEI = 'backupOk'
          GROUP BY NODEID) E
  WHERE E.LAST_BACKUP_TIME < SYSDATE - INTERVAL '2' DAY;
```

This will report on nodes where a backup hasn't been run in the past 48 hours.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Just some minor changes and that should be fine: "SYSDATE" becomes "now()" and "INTERVAL '2' DAY" becomes "'2 days'::interval" or "interval '2 days'"